# Issue Calculating Mean of Grouped Data for entire range of dataset using Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, group-by, mean

I have a data set of daily temperatures for which I want to calculate 20 year means. The data look like this:

```
1974  1  1  5.3  4.6  7.3  3.4  
1974  1  2  3.3  7.2  4.5  6.5  
...
2005  12  364  4.2  5.2  3.3  4.6
2005  12  365  3.1  5.5  2.6  6.8
```

There is no header in the file but the first column contains the year, the second column the month, and the third column the day of the year. The rest of the columns are temperature data.

I want to calculate the average temperature for each day over a period of 20 years. I thought the best way to do that would be to group the data by day and calculate the mean of each day for a specific range of years. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

hist_fn = 'tmean_daily_1974_2005.txt'
twenty_year_fn = '20_yr_mean_1974_1993.txt'

start = 1974
end = 1993

hist_mean = pd.read_csv(hist_fn, sep='\s+', header=None)

# Limit dataframe to only the 20 years for which I want the mean calculated
interval_mean = hist_mean[(hist_mean[0]>=start) & (hist_mean[0]<=end)]

# Rename the first column to reflect what mean this file is displaying
interval_mean.iloc[:, 0] = ("%s-%s" % (start, end))

# Generate mean for each day spread across all the years in the dataframe
interval_mean.iloc[:, 3:] = interval_mean.groupby(2, as_index=False).mean().iloc[:, 2:]

# Write multiyear mean to txt
interval_mean.to_csv(twenty_year_fn, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
```

The data set spans longer than 20 years and the method I used has worked for the first 20 year interval but gives me a (mostly) empty text file for any other set of years entered.

So when I use these inputs it works:

```
start = 1974
end = 1993
```

and it produces a file that looks like this:

```
1974-1993  1  1  4.33  5.25  6.84  3.67  
1974-1993  1  2  7.23  6.22  5.65  6.23  
...
1974-1993  12  364  5.12  4.34  5.21  2.16
1974-1993  12  365  4.81  5.95  3.56  6.78
```

but when I change the inputs to this:

```
start = 1975
end = 1994
```

it produces a .txt file with no temperatures:

```
1975-1994  1  1    
1975-1994  1  2    
...
1975-1994  12  364  
1975-1994  12  365
```

I don't understand why this method works for the first 20 year interval but none of the subsequent intervals. Is it something to do with the way the data is organized or how it is being sliced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now when that's out of the way, we can talk about the problem you presented:

The strange behavior is due to the fact that **pandas matches indices on assignment**, and **slicing preserves the original indices**. That means that when setting

```
interval_mean.iloc[:, 3:] = interval_mean.groupby(2, as_index=False).mean().iloc[:, 2:]
```

Note that `interval_mean.groupby(2, as_index=False).mean()` has indices `0, ... , 30` (since `as_index=False` makes the groupby operation create new indices. Otherwise, it would have been the day number).On the other had, `interval_mean` has the original indices from `hist_mean`, meaning the first time (first 20 years) it has the indices `0, ..., ~20*365` and the second time is has indices starting from arround `20*365` and counting up.

This is a bit confusing at first, but pandas offer great [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) about it, and people quickly discover why it is so useful. 
I'll to explain what happens with an example:

Assume we have the following `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(np.random.randint(5, size=30), [-1,3]))
df

   0  1  2
0  1  1  2
1  2  1  1
2  0  1  2
3  0  2  0
4  2  1  0
5  0  1  2
6  2  2  1
7  1  0  2
8  0  1  0
9  1  2  0
```

Note that the column names are `0,1,2` and the row names (the index) are `0, ..., 9`.

When we preform `groupby` we obtain

```
df.groupby(0, as_index=False).mean()

   0         1         2
0  0  1.250000  1.000000
1  1  1.000000  1.333333
2  2  1.333333  0.666667
```

(The index equals to the columns grouped by just because draw numbers between `0` to `2`). Now, when will do assignments to `df.loc`, it will replace every cell by the corresponding cell in the assignee, if such cell exists. Otherwise, it will leave `NA`.

```
df.loc[:,:] = df.groupby(0, as_index=False).mean()
df

     0         1         2
0  0.0  1.250000  1.000000
1  1.0  1.000000  1.333333
2  2.0  1.333333  0.666667
3 NaN  NaN       NaN
4 NaN  NaN       NaN
5 NaN  NaN       NaN
6 NaN  NaN       NaN
7 NaN  NaN       NaN
8 NaN  NaN       NaN
9 NaN  NaN       NaN
```

And when you write `NA` to csv, it leaves the cell blank.

The last piece of the puzzle is how `interval_mean` preserved the original indices, but this is because slicing preserves the original indices:

```
df[df[1] > 1]

   0  1  2
3  0  2  0
6  2  2  1
9  1  2  0
```

Comment: The second part of your answer pointed me to the right sections in the documentation and correctly addressed the issue. The first part was not necessary though, since I do want means for each day of the year over a multi-year period. Can you delete the first section of the post since it does not address the question?

Comment: Done. Just note that your code consider the following as one group  `[01-01-1974, 01-02-1974, 01-03-1974, ..., 01-12-1974, 01-01-1975, ...]` (and produce one row for it). I don't think it counts as "each day of the year over a multi-year period".